# ruby-on-rails Heroku deployment crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This is the message I get from Heroku:

*Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.*

Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2014-04-08T22:02:13.178588+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create` by xxxx@.com
2014-04-08T22:02:18.527588+00:00 heroku[run.8019]: State changed from starting to up
2014-04-08T22:02:18.788718+00:00 heroku[run.8019]: Awaiting client
2014-04-08T22:02:18.828968+00:00 heroku[run.8019]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:create`
2014-04-08T22:02:22.272358+00:00 heroku[run.8019]: Process exited with status 0
2014-04-08T22:02:22.284341+00:00 heroku[run.8019]: State changed from up to complete
2014-04-08T22:02:48.921183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-04-08T22:02:52.316261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 4765`
2014-04-08T22:02:53.429918+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2014-04-08T22:02:53.429929+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2014-04-08T22:02:54.847354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-04-08T22:02:54.832762+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-04-08T22:02:56.215218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-castle-7002.herokuapp.com request_id=feed828c-36f7-494b-9fc7-373682fe93fa fwd="150.131.104.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-08T22:02:56.605129+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-castle-7002.herokuapp.com request_id=89331d0e-764e-4a2e-be91-a6b687f5016c fwd="150.131.104.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Would someone mind explaining what this means? It runs perfectly fine locally on my computer. 
Thanks.

EDIT:*Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'draper', '~> 1.0'
gem 'js-routes'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

group :development do
  gem 'thin'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'log_buddy'
end

group :production do
    gem "pg"
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Problem 2: after thin gem removal. Heroku Logs:

```
2014-04-08T22:26:06.268271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-castle-7002.herokuapp.com request_id=0a8782a3-e8e4-45b2-b642-23bb2519283f fwd="150.131.104.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-08T22:26:06.597458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-castle-7002.herokuapp.com request_id=d4bafa55-9945-436b-be44-102542c539fb fwd="150.131.104.237" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: can you show your gem file?

Comment: Sure thing! Check above.

Comment: move gem 'thin' out of development block.

Comment: ahhh. I'm seeing where it crashes. Looking into thin and heroku now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you don't have thin in your prod gemset

Take the `group :development` out from around the `gem thin` line.

Heroku isn't downloading a gem (thin) needed to be your webserver

**EDIT**

The key line in troublshooting from all that log output is

`app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin`

That means that bundler is trying to boot up your app, but doesn't know about something called `thin`. How do you 'teach' your app about new things? The gemfile. That's the thought process I ran through.

Heroku always sets `RAILS_ENV` to `:production` by default, which will only install gems from the default or production gemsets. That was the core issue here.

Comment: You're totally right, that was problem 1. My next problem is this. Please see my revision. Not sure what it means, tried removing favicon.ico file from my project and then pushed up to heroku and still no good.

Comment: I'm thinking this is more of a Heroku problem than it is mine? 503 typically means that there's maintenance done on the server itself, right?

Comment: Probably not. Code H10 is 'app crashed', as indicated by the rest of the error message. Try a `heroku restart`, and see what is spit out during that process

Comment: Figured it out. Heroku bases their apps on performance. I would then need to have more web-dynos to increase my performance rate or reorganize my code to be more efficient.